# IEnumerable interface definition

Tags: c#, .net, collections, enumeration, icollection

I took a look at the definition of the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface

```
public interface IEnumerable
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An System.Collections.IEnumerator object that can be used to iterate through
        //     the collection.
        [DispId(-4)]
        IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    }
```

I don't understand what is this attribute `[DispId(-4)]` and why its value is equal to `-4` ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d857b537(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think it is not duplicate, because I ask also about the value -4, why not -3 or even another value

Comment: Well with the duplicate it's now linked to and the link I gave, you have a pretty good answer.